# How can I filter data returned from jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scope, jquery-traversing

**jQuery code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#s-results').load('get_report1.php').show();
  $('#search-btn').click(function(){ showValues(); });
  $(function() {
    $('form').bind('submit', function() { showValues(); return false; });
  });

  function showValues() { 
    $.post('get_report1.php', { name: form.name.value }, 
      function(result) {
        $('#s-results').html(result).show();
      }
    ); 
  }
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<form name = "form">
   <div>Enter name</div>
     <input type="text" name="name" id="fn" />
     <input type="submit" value="Search" id="search-btn" />
   <div>
      <input type="text" id="se2" name="search22">
   </div>
</form>
<div id = "s-results" style="height:50px;">
</div>
```

Up to this the script is running perfectly. Now I just want to filter the returned HTML from the above function again.

For implementing this I have tried this line of code:

```
$(result).filter('#se2');
```

under the function with the `result` parameter, but it is not working.

So how can the returned HTML code be filtered?

Answer (score 6):

You probably need `find()` instead of `filter` as you need to get the descendant whereas filter "*Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or pass the function's test*"

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EM8A5/)**

```
$(result).find('#se2');
```

If the `#se` is added in `DOM` then you can directly use the id selector

```
se = $('#se2');
```

I made another demo (as I am still waiting for your demo that is not working) to further elaborate how a string containing the html you have could be passed to `jQuery` function `$()` to search elements within it using find.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EM8A5/1/)**

```
html = '<form name = "form"> \
   <div>Enter name</div> \
     <input type="text" name="name" id="fn" /> \
     <input type="submit" value="Search" id="search-btn" /> \
   <div> \
       <input type="text" id="se2" name="search22" value="se2"/> \
   </div> \
</form>\
<div id = "s-results" style="height:50px;"> \
</div> ';

alert($(html).find('#se2').val());
```

**Note** You can further check the code working in the example above by using `find` **wont work** by using `filter` over this [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/EM8A5/2/)

Comment: Why not just `$('#se')`?

Comment: Yes it could be used.

Comment: Thanx fr ur suggestion, i hv tried find() instead of filter bt still is not working the way i want.....i hv one que. that for finding any text in returned html , is there any need of event to be fired like onclick event or onkeyup....??

Comment: Please check demo over here or make a fiddle?

Comment: Data returned from jquery is in table format.....i just want way so that i can again filter or find any text in that data table....returned from jquery and php....

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Answer (score 2):

#### The issue

You are successfully adding the `result` to `#s-results`:

```
$('#s-results').html(result).show();
```

And then tried to select `#se2` from the added `results` like this, with no success:

```
$(result).filter('#se2');
```

It didn't work because you didn't get it from the dom added in the second step.

Actually, it is creating a ***new unattached*** dom with the same `result` variable.

---

#### The solution

To select `#se2` from the added `result` content correctly, try the following:

```
$('#s-results').filter('#se2');
```

Or, as suggested by @zerkms, you could select it directly through:

```
$('#se2');
```

These possibilities will work, because now it is referencing something attached to dom, which will search into the same elements you added in the first step.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use `ajax` for this as below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#s-results').load('get_report1.php').show();
    $('#search-btn').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "get_report1.php",
            data: {
                name: $("#fn").val()
            },
            beforeSend: function () {
                //do stuff like show loading image until you get response
            },
            success: function (result) {
                $('#s-results').html(result).show();
            },
            error: function (e) {
                alert("Error in ajax call " + e);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**Note:** When you click on search-btn each time it will call the `get_report1.php` file and retrieve the data base on the text-box value that you have passed. I assume that in `ge_report1.php` file you are using the tex-box value like: `$_POST['name']` and you are fetching the data using `MySQL` search query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JQuery` `find` instead of filter.

```
$(result).find('#se2');
```

Then add to your variable like this

```
var your_element = $('#se2');
```